# Limit the visibility of comments on the Disqus private page

Tags: private, privacy, disqus

If I embed Disqus on a private page, my comments on the page will still be visible on the Discus site (https://disqus.com/home/forums/your_site/). Is it possible to somehow hide them on Disqus so that they are visible only on the page of my site?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please show your research which didn't work for you

Comment: @SaachiTech I want to embed comments on a private page. I was able to embed Disqus on my page, but now comments on the private page can be seen by everyone registered on Disqus. Can I restrict access to comments from my page only